# Elasticsearch: How do I find the same field name across multiple indices?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to find out which of my ES indices contain a filed named "book_id".
I'm trying to use this query:

```
GET */_search
{
 "query": {
    "term": {
      "field_name": {
        "value": "book_id",
        "boost": 1.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

as well as the same query run against /_mapping.

What I am hoping to retrieve is a list of indices, in which the documents contain the "book_id" field.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate on the [`_index` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html):

```
{
  "query": {...},
  "aggs": {
    "by_index": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will return the amount of documents matching your query grouped by index. You might need to change the `size` parameter or use a [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) when you have a lot of indices.

Comment: what endpoint will this query run against?

Comment: The same endpoint you were using! See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html

Answer (score 0):

You can search on all indices and aggregate over the `_index` meta field to get your desired result.

Here is the complete elastic query to do that -

```
POST /_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "book_id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "indexes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```